# Integrating netty with the web container

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, netty, nio

I'm a newbie to netty. I want to use Netty in a web container(say servlet) for a web app that I'm developing. So that I hit the servlet from the front end and get back the result from netty. The thing is I dont want to make use of web sockets. Is there a way to go about doing this. It would be great if you can point me to some links. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cgbystrom/jersey-netty
I dont know  whether jersey can meet your requirement?